# Unable to resolve module expo-constants

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I was installed an expo-constant for a test after that I unistalled the expo-constant by

> npm uninstall expo-constants

Now when I run my app an error appears:

> Unable to resolve module expo-constants from
> C:\Users..\node_modules\expo-font\build\FontLoader.js: expo-constants
> could not be found within the project.

Any ideas on what else I can try to resolve this?

The full error below:

```
If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  1 | import { CodedError } from '@unimodules/core';
  2 | import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
> 3 | import Constants from 'expo-constants';
    |                        ^
  4 | import { Platform } from 'react-native';
  5 | import ExpoFontLoader from './ExpoFontLoader';
  6 | const isInClient = Constants.appOwnership === 'expo';
```

Comment: you're still using the constants somewhere or it's being cached. Make sure expo-constants is not in Package.json and then Delete your package-lock.json and do an expo install. If it doesn't work, it means you're still using it somewhere.

Comment: It still not working I removed the package-lock and expo install, for the expo-constants I didn't use it anywhere

Comment: Did you run expo start -c after reinstalling? (-c is to reset cache)

Answer (score 1):

Try Updating packages to the latest version.

```
npm update
```

give a try to install with `--force` flag as well if the update has not worked. eg:

```
npm install --force
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add this in your package.json

> "expo-yarn-workspaces": {
> "symlinks": ["expo-constants"]   }

Regards